# AWS SFTP Password and Key based Authentication

Tags: sftp, amazon-web-services

I have a scenario where I need to implement both password and key-based authentication for the AWS SFTP in my project. We have AWS EFS as the backend for our SFTP. This is one of the documentation that we found on AWS: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/storage/enable-password-authentication-for-aws-transfer-for-sftp-using-aws-secrets-manager/ but this has some limitations because of which we aren't able to proceed with this approach. Is there any other method of achieving this use case?

Comment: Please add to your post which limitations are not acceptable.

Comment: Also, you should note that the link you sent has been updated with newer information. There is an update at the top of the article you shared